# what does scale3d() function really do?

Tags: css

**scale3d(sx, sy, sz)**

I can't understand what scale3d() really do when I change (sz) Value

In this below code you can see the value of (sz) is = 1

```css
body{perspective:600px}
div{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: burlywood;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius:40px;
    transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
    transform: scale3d(1,1,1)
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

In this below code you can see the value of (sz) is = 0.5

but nothing changed the same result

```css
body{perspective:600px}
div{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: burlywood;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius:40px;
    transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
    transform: scale3d(1,1,0.5)
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Note :** I tried all solutions & values but nothing happened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third number in `scale3d` is for the z-axis, which is only applicable to three-dimensional shapes.

Your examples have perspective, but they're still just use two-dimensional shapes, so nothing happens.

You can see the effect with a true cube:

### scale3d(1,1,1)

```css
#wrapper {
  perspective: 1200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 80px auto;
}
#cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(45deg) scale3d(1, 1,1);
  transition: transform 1s;
}
#cube>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
}
#cube>div span {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 50px;
}
#left {
  background-color: rgba(25, 25, 112, 0.7);
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
#right {
  background-color: rgba(47, 79, 79, 0.7);
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
#front {
  background-color: rgba(119, 136, 153, 0.7);
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(100px);
}
#back {
  background-color: rgba(72, 61, 139, 0.7);
  transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(100px);
}
#top {
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 128, 0.7);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
#bottom {
  background-color: rgba(70, 130, 180, 0.7);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="cube">
    <div id="left"><span>left</span></div>
    <div id="right"><span>right</span></div>
    <div id="front"><span>front</span></div>
    <div id="back"><span>back</span></div>
    <div id="top"><span>top</span></div>
    <div id="bottom"><span>bottom</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### scale3d(1,1,0.5)

```css
#wrapper {
  perspective: 1200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
#cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(45deg) scale3d(1,1,0.5);
  transition: transform 1s;
}
#cube > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
}
#cube > div span {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 50px;
}
#left {
  background-color: rgba(25,25,112,0.7);
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
#right {
  background-color: rgba(47,79,79,0.7);
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
#front  {
  background-color: rgba(119,136,153,0.7);
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(100px);
}
#back {
  background-color: rgba(72,61,139,0.7);
  transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(100px);
}
#top {
  background-color: rgba(0,128,128,0.7);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
#bottom {
  background-color: rgba(70,130,180,0.7);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="cube">
    <div id="left"><span>left</span></div>
    <div id="right"><span>right</span></div>
    <div id="front"><span>front</span></div>
    <div id="back"><span>back</span></div>
    <div id="top"><span>top</span></div>
    <div id="bottom"><span>bottom</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . But I want to learn how to make 3d shapes with css3

Comment: @Ahmed 3D shapes in CSS are basically just a bunch of 2D shapes positioned so their edges meet. The shapes aren't truly 3D in that they're always hollow. (That's why there's opacity in my snippets above; to help illustrate this point.) You can use your browser console or a site like JS Fiddle or CodePen to experiment with transforming divs to get different effects. [Here's a blog](https://davidwalsh.name/css-cube) where you can follow along to learn how to make a cube. [Here's another](https://css-tricks.com/creating-a-3d-cube-image-gallery/).

Answer (score 0):

What is [Scale3d](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale3d)?

*(Sample at end, see link)*

*Your 1st code:*

```
transform: scale3d(1,1,1)
```

*Your 2nd code:*

```
transform: scale3d(1,1,0.5)
```

*This is:*

```
scale3d ( <scaling-value-x> , <scaling-value-y> , <scaling-value-z> )
```

Your example is a 2d shape with no effect thats why. **Z pane** is used to make 3d objects.

[image]

> [Try Here](https://dev.opera.com/articles/understanding-3d-transforms/scale3d.html) and see how it works.

Comment: Thanks for your help